# How to pass query string in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, modern-experience, json-formatting

I want to pass a query-string in the URL whenever I click on the custom button in a SharePoint column.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: How did you create a button in SharePoint column? Do you want to refresh the page after passing query string parameter in URL?

Comment: I basically changed the json of a column. I want a re-direct the user to different page on click.

Comment: Is "different" page URL & query string parameter name same for all list item buttons?

Comment: Yes, page URL & query string parameter name same for all list item buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using JSON formatting to create a button in list view, you can use JSON similar to below to pass query string parameter in URL:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='https://www.google.com/search?q=' + [$Title]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Go to Client Data",
      "style": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "width": "100%"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I am passing list item **Title** dynamically to query string parameter named `q`.

**Update**:

To pass the document URL in query string parameter, replace `[$Title]` with `[$FileRef]` like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='https://www.google.com/search?q=' + [$FileRef]",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "style": {
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "txtContent": "Go to Client Data",
      "style": {
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "width": "100%"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It will generate link URL like:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=/sites/SiteName/LibraryName/Document.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. But is there any way to pass document path in the query string dynamically?

Comment: Check updated answer to pass document URL in query string parameter

Comment: Thanks again brother.  Upvote(^) and accept as an Answer done.